# Element not visible as both the menu and submenu hidden

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to open  cric info and then click on 'live score'menu when the submenu opens, click on 'Desktop scoreboard'.

But the problem is live score menu is under a div which is hidden.
ie  and this div is under td

"You can check the structure of the page to get detailed info"

so when i try to click the menu element using driver.findElementBy("xpath") i got the element not visible exception.

So i directly used the javascript used by the developer mopen('m2') which does the job of opening the menu but after this when i execute the command to find the submenu element again get the same error"Element not visible exception".

Tried making div visible by executing jscript.

PFB the code i used:

```
FirefoxDriver d1=new FirefoxDriver();
    d1.get("http://www.cricinfo.com");
    ((JavascriptExecutor) d1).executeScript("mopen('m2')");
    ((JavascriptExecutor) d1).executeScript("document.getElementById('m2').style.visibility='visible';");
    ((JavascriptExecutor) d1).executeScript("document.getElementById('m2').style.display='block';");
    d1.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    d1.findElementByXPath("//*[@id='mgDdRht']/tbody/tr[3]/td/a").click();
```

Also tried using the Actions class but everything in vain ,help is really appreciated
Thanks in advance.

Comment: <td class="navLinks" onmouseout="mclosetime()" onmouseover="mopen('m2')">
<a class="NavLink" href="/ci/engine/current/match/scores/live.html">Live Scores</a>
<div id="m2" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left">
<tbody>
<tr>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="ddTabLeft" width="4" height="27"></td>
<td class="PopupTabs">
<a class="popNavLink" name="&lpos=cricinfo_mainnav&lid=livescores" href="/ci/engine/current/match/scores/live.html">Live Scores</a>
</td>

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with an `Action` chain:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(d1);
Action clickSubMenu = builder.moveToElement(d1.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Nav td:nth-child(2).navLinks")))
    .moveToElement(d1.findElement(By.cssSelector("#m0 td:nth-child(1)#mgDd>table:nth-child(1)>tbody:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2).PopupTabs")))
    .click(d1.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='mgDdRht']/tbody/tr[3]/td/a"))).build();

clickSubMenu.perform();
```

I tested this in c#, and it worked for me.  I translated it to Java, but I may have made a syntactical error.  Apologies if I have.

What I found is that I needed to move to Series.  Then I had to move to Series - the dropdown version, as the dropdown version of Series is a different element than the non-dropdown version.  Then I was able to move to the West Indies link, and click it.

Comment: Hi Richard,I don't have idea about finding the elements using cssSelector and not able to do it using xpath as in cricinfo all the menu elements have the same xpath if u check it....Do u have ne other solution to click the submenu after making the menu visible as all the submenus have the correct xpath....And please correct if i have done any mistakes in my approach above